# How to run a sql query in C# and asp.net and show the result in csv file locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I don't have permission to create files on the server so, I cannot write to file and then show it to user. I am trying to redirect the query result to a file which user can open/save locally in their computers.

Comment: OK, good luck. Let us know if you get stuck :-)

Comment: What did you try, and what errors did you get?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I managed to figure out the solution. I executed the query and saved it in a Dataset. Read all the results from dataset and saved the result comma separated in a string. When the user clicks the button the query will be executed and they will be prompted to save the output.

```
String str; // this has the results of query in csv
string file_name; // name of the file,
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file_name + "\"");
Response.Write(str);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```